# Get distance to border in 2d grid with numpy/scypi

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a 2D map in which every square belongs to different players or no one. Tiles belonging to a player are side by side and are usually enclosed by tiles that don't belong to anyone. The map has no boundary but wraps around.

**I would like to get the distance from each tile to the border of tiles that belong to no one**. Currently I use following BFS-algorithm:

```
def get_distances(self):
    distances = np.zeros((self.width, self.height), dtype=np.int)

    unknown = [square for square in self if square.owner == None]
    toVisit = deque(unknown)
    visited = set(toVisit)

    while toVisit:
        curr = toVisit.popleft()
        visited.add(curr)

        for direction in (NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST):
            neighbor = self.get_target(temp, direction)
            if n not in visited:
                toVisit.append(neighbor)
                visited.add(neighbor)
                distances[neighbor.x, neighbor.y] = distances[curr.x, curr.y] + 1

    return distances
```

Since I need to calculate this very often, performance matters. I already use numpy and scipy to create things like diffusion maps for which [`scipy.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) has been extraordinary helpful and fast. Besides that, I don't have a lot of experience with both libraries and need some external help to find the things I require. Can you help?

Comment: Check out the [distance transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_edt.html).

Comment: Thank you, `scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_cdt` with `metric='taxicab'` is what I'm looking for. However, my map wraps around on the edges and this function can't consider this

Comment: Yes, the wrap around isn’t usually a part of image processing workflows… a simple solution might be to pad your map above/below/left/right with a copy of itself, though that might make the distance transform too expensive 